# Secure String - is it still worth it?

Tags: .net

Is there any value in using secure string to store sensitive data within an application?

Would there be better alternative approaches, as the secure string recommendation is very outdated.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

Comment: "Is there any value in using secure string to store sensitive data within an application?" - No; "the secure string recommendation is very outdated" - no, the explicit recommendation not to use ("We don't recommend that you use the SecureString class for new development.") it is still entirely timely, correct, and relevant :)

Comment: It is a .NET 1.x class.  Back then there were still reasonable odds that somebody might use Marshal.SecureStringToXxx() to interop with unmanaged code.  The other important part of a secure string, actually using it.  Those days are over.

Comment: Microsoft's guidance is to not use SecureString. However to my knowledge they have not bothered to offer a replacement, so practically it's still good to use it *instead of* a non-secure string, because, all else being equal, the security is greater with SecureString than without... objectively. Whether it is "worth it", however, is a matter of opinion. Ideally, the thought is you would not use strings to store sensitive information. Practically, that still happens a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FROM: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

> ## DE0001: SecureString shouldn't be used
>
> ### Motivation
>
> - The purpose of [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) is to avoid having secrets stored in the process   memory as plain text.
> - However, even on Windows, [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) doesn't exist as an OS concept.   * It just makes the window getting the plain
>   text shorter; it doesn't fully
>   prevent it as .NET still has to convert the string to a plain text
>   representation.   * The benefit is that the plain text representation doesn't hang around
>   as an instance of [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string) -- the lifetime of the native buffer is
>   shorter.
> - The contents of the array is unencrypted except on .NET Framework.   * In .NET Framework, the contents of the internal char array is encrypted.
>   .NET doesn't support encryption in all environments, either
>   due to missing APIs or key management issues.
>
> ### Recommendation
>
> Don't use [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) for new code. When porting
> code to .NET Core, consider that the contents of the array are not
> encrypted in memory.
>
> The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and
> instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or
> Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For other's benefit, there is an interesting discussion that I will link to, where answer #4 goes into what I believe is a good detail of why SecureString was (or is) useful, and why it wasn't.

Specifically, that a standard string is immutable, C# does not provide access to SecureZeroMemory by nature,and we have no say in the lifetime of that data. Sometimes you need to collect data in the form of a string that is (by good practice, compliance, regulations, etc.) needing to be protected as much as possible. This answer provides some suggestions, such as a char array, that have an easier path to controlling that data. New technologies and APIs will certainly come along but I thought this answer was extremely well thought out instead of simply a cut-and-paste of the Microsoft official warning.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30309583)

Comment: @fidelisoris, where is the link?

Comment: Ah, I wish that link was still active